# REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, No body specified in the file attachment:

Tags: email, attachment

I have a requirement whenever I create a record and upload a word file document in notes and attachment a trigger gets fired which send that attachment to a desired email address.

I have written this trigger which sends email when a record is created but when I try to add attachment code it shows this error.
REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, No body specified in the file attachment:
But when I check in debug I get the Body as Blob[0].

```
trigger SendMail on Random__c (after update) 
{

Set<ID> RandomIDs = new Set<ID>();
for(Random__c c : trigger.new)
{
    RandomIDs.add(c.id);

}
  List<Attachment> lstAttach = [SELECT id, Name, body, ContentType FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId IN : RandomIDs];
 for(Candidate__c c : trigger.new)
{

   Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

    for(Attachment att : lstAttach)
    {
         // Create the email attachment

         Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();       
         efa.setFileName(att.Name);
         efa.Body = att.body;
         efa.setContentType('application/msWord');
         efa.setInline(false);
     email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});

    }



    String subject = 'Sample subject ';
    email.setSubject(subject);

    String body = ' Sample Body '; 
    email.setPlainTextBody(body);

    email.setToAddresses(new String[]{'test@test.com'});

    if(email != null)
      {

        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.singleEmailMessage[] {email});

      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be any of below reason .

1. It seems to me that you are not using the correct method to attach a file as email attachment.
   There is  no **body** method for **EmailFileAttachment** object

attach.Body = fileBody;
--> should really be --> 
 attach.setBody = fileBody;

2. Avoid hardcoding contentType. Directly use **attach.contentType**
3. When you say you get value in **body**. Ensure that you are checking the *attachment body* and not the *email body*.
4. Also you used Candidate__c and Random__c for looping through trigger.new. Hope both are one and the same.

I tried out the exact code that you used and it works great for me without any error.

Comment: I have tried attach.setBody = fileBody; syntax before but was still getting the same error.

Comment: Hey Amit, I have previously used hardcoded contentType. And the body I am checking is of attachment object for sure. And Candidate and Random are same.

Answer (score 0):

Animesh,

I do not see any DML operations in the code snippet shown above. Can you please post the code snippet for this which results in the trigger being invoked.

The "REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING" error may occur due to a field or attribute value for a certain mandatory field on the record not being set with a value while performing a DML which in your case would be on the Notes and Attachment standard object.

Also please ensure that the ParentId field on Attachment has a valid record id specified. Refer https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000096viIAA.